# Can you code an ARM application for both Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, arm

I have been looking into developing in ARM architecture. I noticed that both Android and IOS devices run off of ARM processors, and wondered if one full-scale application written in ARM assembly could be run on both an iPhone and an Android device.

Comment: firefox and chrome can run on foreign platforms but that is by design there is a common abstraction layer then somewhere there has to be a platform specific layer.   so you would have to develop some percentage of your program above a layer you create then the operating and target specific layers are incompatible and then you end up with two or more binaries.  but you could make a percentage of your program compatible yes just like you can have most of one program compatible across windows linux and macos...

Answer (score 0):

YEs and no.  Compiled ARM code will run on both, and a common way of sharing code between the two platforms is to write it in C or C++ and compile it to shared libraries.  But the two take different file formats for their executables, and interacting with the various UI, input, etc libraries will be different.  So it's really only usable for pur logic.